# Generic way to Escape Quotes in Javascript Variable

Tags: javascript, jquery, escaping, quotes

I have a form where users can enter any HTML.

```
var title = "Cool <a href="http://google.com">Check This</a>"
```

As you can see, the variable is having `"` but it can be also `'`. It causes an error if there is `"`. What is better way to fix this? Storing escaped string in database like below?

```
$title = str_replace('"', "'", $_REQUEST['title']); // Replace double quote with single quote as js variable above is wrapped with double quotes.
```

Or escape it before showing on page? Anything in jQuery like escape that can help here?

Comment: @Alex: That's wrong. If you have something like `<span title="This link leads to awesome stuff."></span>` it will be converted to `<span title=This link leads to awesome stuff></span>`. As result, only `This` will appear after hovering on text.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var title="Cool <a href=\"http://google.com\">Check This</a>"
```

Well, you cannot escape it using JavaScript because JavaScript needs to see what you want to escape and you want to escape that. If you use PHP, you can use `addslashes()` prior to inserting into JavaScript.

Anyways, you should be careful of allowing to insert any HTML. Wrongly escaped HTML (like allowing to insert `<script>`) can allow to do various dangerous stuff, like stealing all cookies.

Comment: `htmlspecialchars` is much nicer.

Comment: @Alex: Uhmmm... that's not problem. The problem is that value contains `"` which is used to store it. `htmlspecialchars()` would replace `"` with `&quot;` and `<` with `&lt;` making HTML unusable.

Comment: Then use `htmlspecialchars_decode ();`? I was hoping that was also implied.